# Which event is responsible for after Customer account reset password?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I need event after **customer reset passoword** successful or unsuccessful to perform next operation but I am unable to get any proper solution.

event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_resetpasswordpost">
        <observer name="rave_customer_forgot_link" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Observer\PostdispatchCustomerAccountResetpasswordObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

PostdispatchCustomerAccountResetpasswordObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace  Namespace\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;


class PostdispatchCustomerAccountResetpasswordObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
    }

    /**
     * customer register event handler
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        //How I will get customer email id here ?
        die('FDFASDFDS');
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421816/magento-change-email-in-forgotpassword-before-check-it 
This is for Magento 1.9 but you can use the same event and wrap condition with 'change_password'.

Comment: Amit Saini I tried but it is not working .

Comment: Ok, After the password reset "customer_save_before" event working or not?

Comment: * Amit Saini * customer_save_before event will work in every condition I need event only when reset password .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to create a plugin that is called after the password reset (It is done in Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement::resetPassword()):

1. di.xml (in my case I put in etc/frontend/di.xml because I only needed in frontend)

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement">
           <plugin name="name_of_your_plugin" type="nameSpace_of_your_module\AccountManagement" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
       </type>
   </config>
   ```
2. Plugin file

   ```
   use Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement as BaseAccountManagement 

   class AccountManagement
   {
   public function __construct()
   {

   }


   /**
    * @param BaseAccountManagement $accountManagement
    * @param $result
    * @param $email
    * @param $resetToken
    * @param $newPassword
    * @return mixed
    */
   public function afterResetPassword(BaseAccountManagement $accountManagement, $result, $email, $resetToken, $newPassword)
   {
       if ($result)
       {
           //Do your stuff here when reset was successfull
       }
       else
       {
           //Do your stuff here when reset went wrong
       }

       //always return result
       return $result;
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create "`Post Dispatch`" or "`Pre Dispatch`" event for this controller according to your requirement.

> Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ResetPasswordPost.php

This controller is call when you post reset password form.

Comment: first I need to create Plugin for Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ResetPasswordPost and I will add my custom event in that after that I will use my event right ?

Comment: You need to use "Pre" or "Post" dispatch event provide by magento default for controller, no need to create anything.

Comment: Sure Dhiren but In observer, I need to load customer will post dispatch event will return me customer information ?

Comment: Because I also need to reset customer password to third part API .

Comment: You need to implement the code, you will get all the data on the observer.

Comment: Hi Dhiren could you please check my updated question!

Comment: Do not update the question totally, If you have new question then ask it separately. And if above answer help you into your query then up-vote and accept as solution so it will help community as well.